# Is Dropbox the best choice for hosting a collection of video files?

Tags: dropbox, online-storage, cloud

I want to share a folder of private videos with another group of viewers. Two schools are twinned with each other, and want to send and view data back and forth.

To allow every child to see every video, is hosting it in my Dropbox folder the best method?

I had considered:

1. YouTube 'non-public' videos (only those with the link can view them; disadvantage is one link needed for every single film)
2. E-mailing the videos (silly idea, each is too big)
3. Burning a CD and posting it (drawback only one copy of lots of copies needed)

Any other sensible and zero-cost suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a private password protected blog on posterous.com (no, I'm not being paid by them nor am I trolling!) is a great way to share videos in an attractive and practical way.  Students can also comment on the videos and develop conversations etc around the videos which is a but nicer and more aesthetically pleasing than just using a Dropbox link.  Also, Dropbox fills up pretty quick if you use video. It's free and you can restrict viewers to those who have the password, so the security is great for schools.

Comment: An even better answer than the last one! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Could it be possible to store the YouTube 'non-public' video link in dropbox? This will make sure you do not fill the dropbox.

Comment: That's such an abviously good solution, I'm embarrassed that I didn't trhink of it! Thank you!